# How to differentiate whether a managed library is running in the context of asp.net application or in a executable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, managed

how to differentiate whether a managed library is running in the context of asp.net application or in a executable?

Comment: You might be better served by telling us exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check whether `HttpContext.Current` returns `null` or not.

Technically, it'll also return `null` in an ASP.NET application if it's running on a non-worker thread (i.e. if you just go `new Thread(SomeProc)`) but it should work 99% of the time.

Comment: Speedy!  :)  It's also possible to "fake" an HttpContext.  So I wouldn't rely on this method.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't really make a lot of sense.  A process is a process.  But you may be able to tell if your library is loaded by ASP.NET by checking to see if HttpContext.Current is null.